# Vb.net attached datafile .mdf data displayed runtime when i close re open application data lost

Tags: vb.net, attachment, mdf

I am using a VB.net application connected with a .mdf database file.

The application is running successfully, and when I try to insert records its accepted.

Everytime I close and reopen the application, new records from previous run disappear. This happens inside the VS IDE when I'm testing it.

What can be happening?

Comment: put your insert code to better solution..

Comment: <add name="Master" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Invent.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    />Local_Declaration.str_SQL = Nothing
            Local_Declaration.str_SQL = "INSERT INTO Suppliers" & _
                      " (SuppName, SuppId
) " & _
                      " VALUES     ('" & txtSuppName.Text & "','" & txtSuppID.Text & "')"
            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectDB.GetConnection_String, CommandType.Text, Local_Declaration.str_SQL)
            MessageBox.Show("New Supplier Added Successfully")

Comment: Tell me that this not happens on debuging or inside the visual studio when you test it?

Comment: Yes inside visual studio when i debug that time i run the insert function its working but again when i close start debug the inserted data not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are debuging your process, VS copy all the needed file to the deploy folder, and the run it. Check that your database is not being copied every time. Copy it only when it changes (you have an option on the file).

Answer (score 2):

This is because on build you are overwriting the database during runtime, with your design time database.

Look at the properties of the Database file and change the "Copy to Output Directory" setting.

Alternatively, use SQL Express directly, and change your connection string so it does not attach the db file every time you build.